# How do you conditionally format a column based on the value of one cel in that column in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

I would like to highlight all columns that contain "Sa" or "Su" in them and leave all other columns unformatted. The sheet is already formatted to change any "Sa" or "Su" cell values to grey.

[image]

I tried using custom formulas but am not sure what the most efficient way to do this is. Is it possible to create one formula that applies to the column? I would think it could work if it highlights any column with an Sa or Su value in Row 2.

Comment: Great Job with the image. You could also make a copy of sheet and share a link give view access. That when it easier for people to jump and help

Answer (score 0):

To create conditional formatting to highlight all columns containing "Sa" or "Su" while keeping other columns unformatted follow these steps:

[image]

1. Select the range of cells where you want to apply the conditional formatting.
2. Click on "Format" in the top menu bar.
3. Choose "Conditional formatting" from the dropdown menu.
4. In the "Conditional format rules" pane that appears on the right-hand side, under "Format cells if," select "Custom formula is."
5. In the text box that appears, enter your formula: `=REGEXMATCH(A2, "Sa|Su")`.
6. Click on the "Formatting style" box to choose the formatting you want to apply. To make the cell background gray, click on the paint bucket icon and select a gray color. You can also adjust other formatting options like font color, borders, etc., as needed.
7. Review your settings, and click the "Done" button to apply the conditional formatting.

The selected range of cells will now be highlighted in gray if the formula `=REGEXMATCH(A2, "Sa|Su")` evaluates to true for each cell in the range. You can adjust the range and formatting settings as needed.

#### Edit:

As mentioned before Select the range of cells where you want to apply the conditional formatting.

To adjust the range:

1. Select the range D1:NE37 by clicking and dragging your mouse over the cells or by manually typing D1:NE37 into the cell selection field at the top left of your Google Sheets window.
2. Click on "Format" in the top menu bar.
3. Choose "Conditional formatting" from the dropdown menu.
4. In the "Conditional format rules" pane that appears on the right-hand side, under "Format cells if," select "Custom formula is."
5. In the text box that appears, enter your formula: `=REGEXMATCH(D1, "Sa|Su")` (Note that we've adjusted the formula to refer to the first cell in the selected range, D1, instead of A2).
6. Click on the "Formatting style" box to choose the formatting you want to apply (e.g., gray background color).
7. Review your settings, and click the "Done" button to apply the conditional formatting.

The conditional formatting will now be applied to the range D1:NE37, and cells meeting the criteria specified by the formula will be highlighted in gray.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! It seems that even though I have it applying to range D1:NE37 it only applies the formatting to Row 1. Do you know why this is?

Comment: @Alex The answer is being updated. Take a look.